# How to hide share content option under profile type?

Tags: users

There is an option "Share Content" under every profile type. It is being displayed to all users apart from admin. I just want to hide it. I searched for it enabling Devel module but did not get anything belongs to the option. Please share your answer if anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is a field, so under Profile2 you can change 'Manage Display' for all fields - set it hidden